# Path compression with a quick union algorithm, java

Tags: java, algorithm, compression

Given the following block of code, taken from a quickunion algorithm, I need to add a loop to the method find() that links every site in the path from a site p to the root. I have seen some other similar questions and answers on this site, but the answers seem to differ from one another, and I don't believe they perform compression in the way I am trying to do it. Any help at all would be very much appreciated!

```
public int find(int p)
{   //Find component name.      
while (p != id[p]) p = id[p];
return p;
}

public void union(int p, int q)
{   //Give p and q the same root.
int i = find(p);
int j = find(q);
if (i==j) return;

id[i] = j;

count--;
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you found a bunch of different ways to perform path compression? Is that a problem? There surely isn't just one way to do it - that's more often than not the case. What's "the way [you're] trying to [(or want to)] do it"?

Comment: What are the other examples you saw and how do they differ?

Comment: Yes there are many ways for sure. Other examples that I saw would perform compression by linking the site to its grandparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with double loop, first find the root, and then set everything to point to it.

```
public int find(int p)
{   int curr = p;
    while (curr != id[curr]) curr = id[curr]; //find root
    //at this point, curr is the root
    while (p != id[p]) { 
        int next = id[p];
        id[p] = curr; //remember, curr is the root
        p = next;
    }
}
```